# How to add a custom menuItem on textview's longPressGesture and call that menuItems action on click?

Tags: swiftui

I need to add 'Highlight' as a new custom menu item on long-press in the textview.
I have been able to remove "Lookup" which I don't need, but unable to figure out how to add the extra menu items.

1. In my SwiftUI code, CustomUITextView extends UITextView,

```
class CustomUITextView: UITextView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:))  ||
            action  == Selector(("_define:")) ||
            action  == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
            action  == Selector(("_promptForReplace:")){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```

2. and TextView conforms to UIViewRepresentable protocol -

```
struct TextView : UIViewRepresentable {

    var contents: NSAttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomUITextView {
        let customTextView = CustomUITextView()
        customTextView.isEditable = false
        customTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return customTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomUITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = contents
    }
}
```

3. In Swift, I know the code to add custom menu items would be this -

```
    func addSpecialMenu() {
        let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
        var menuItem = [UIMenuItem]();
        let highlightMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Highlight", action: #selector(onHighlightClicked));
        menuItem.append(highlightMenuItem);
        menuController.menuItems = menuItem;
    }
```

I tried the calling addSpecialMenu() on longPressGesture. But couldnot get it working.
How can I add a custom menu link in SwiftUI.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement CustomMenu, which exists in SwiftUI.

You declare it like this:

```
Text("Includes hidden menu")
    .contextMenu {
        Button(action: { }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                Text("Delete")
            }
        }
        Button(action: { }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil.tip")
                Text("Highlight")
            }
        }
    }
```

And it is revealed by long pressing on the element it is attached to:

[image: ContextMenu]

Comment: I actually did try context menu and it didn't work out for me. I am doing a Book App, so the textView contains the Chapter contents. On long pressing anywhere, the user will be shown that 'Highlight' menu, using which, he should be able to select a part of text that he wants to highlight. I was unable to do this using context menu. Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is yet another thing missing from SwiftUI. You have to work with UIMenuController for text selection. Difficult to customize with SwiftUI